# How does reactions like these proceed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, amines

*I encountered this question in the chapter Amines and trust me I've gone through many textbooks but couldn't find the functioning of those reagents, well some of them.*

[image: reaction]

Firstly could you explain what does the 3 reagents under the same arrow signify? Also, can you explain the mechanism step by step?

I'd be greatful.

Comment: You could not find out the functioning of the reagents? Come on $\ce{P_4O_{10}}$ removes water, ammonia acts as a base/nucleophile, KOH is a base, Ph-Cl is used as arylating agent and aq. KOH for hydrolysis. That is very standard and really not that difficult. What textbooks where you looking at?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**

1. Your starting material is *o*-phthalic acid.
2. Phosphorous pentoxide, $\ce{P4O10}$, is a strong dehydration agent.
3. The $\Delta$ symbol in your original image means that heat is applied

   What happens here?

   > The intramolecular reaction of the two $\ce{-COOH}$ groups yields [phthalic anhydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phthalic_anhydride).

**Step 2**

1. Carboxylic acids can react with amines to form amides, but what happens here?

   > Anhydrides react with amines to form imides.
   >  Here, the reaction of phthalic anhydride with ammonia yields [phthalimide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phthalimide).

**Step 3**

1. The product of the previous reaction is first reacted with potassium hydroxide, which is a strong base. What could possible happen here?

   > The $\ce{N-H}$ proton of an [imide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imide) can be removed easily. Draw some resonance structures of the anion to see why this is the case!
2. Chlorobenzene ($\ce{Ph-Cl}$) is added.

   > This reaction will furnish *N*-phenyl phthalimide. Read about [nucleophilic aromatic substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleophilic_aromatic_substitution) to understand what is going on here.
3. The product of the previous step is treated with aqueous potassium hydroxide.

   > Read about the hydrolysis of esters, amides, and imides to understand what has happened.

Comment: So it's a Gabriel synthesis.

Comment: @ketbra Yes, as far as the reaction of the imide is concerned. But I tried to keep it simple and give some more general hints instead ;-)

Comment: Yeah it is Gabriel synthesis... Correct

Comment: I would've thought the nucleophilic addition wouldn't have been that great...

Comment: @Zhe I did prepare a lot of phthalimides, but I never used aryl halides. Typically, I reacted phthalic anhydrides with alkyl or arylamines.

Comment: Great answer sir, can you please simplify it and generalise what every reagent is doing and what it's supposed to do otherwise in other reactions?